# Upload excel file and then send data in excel file to database oracle using zk framework

Tags: excel, zk

I want to send data to database from selected excel file by using zk framework. The send button is using to send data from uploaded excel file to data base . Can you give me guide step by step ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NIe3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to go into each aspect of your question:

**DB:** ZK doesn't include/prefer any database layer -> which means you have to choose yourself a library/framework to access your database and store the data, e.g. JDBC, hibernate, JPA, spring-data ... (that's outside the scope of ZK).

**File Upload:** In order to upload a file from a zul page you can use a file upload button:

```
<button upload="true" label="Import"/>
```

Then register an `onUpload` event listener, to handle the uploaded file contents. Retrieved from `UploadEvent.getMedia().getByteData() / .getStreamData()`

**Extract Data from Excel File:** Once you have the binary data, you need to process/parse it (e.g. using the [apache POI library](https://poi.apache.org/)), which then allows you to access specific sheets/regions to extract data. Then use your persistence library from above to store the data into tables as needed.

If you need a manual approach for the user to select which data range to export you can use Keikai to import/display the spreadsheet to the user, let him/her select a region before storing it to a DB (the basics are covered in [this tutorial](https://doc.keikai.io/tutorial/database#))

([duplicate question on zk forum](https://forum.zkoss.org/question/112213/upload-excel-file-and-then-send-data-in-excel-file-to-database-oracle-using-zk-framework/?answer=112227#post-id-112227))